# d3.js force layout not working on jsfiddle and github

Tags: d3.js, svg, jsfiddle, typeerror

**[EDITS in bold]**
I am a beginner with d3.js, and I'm trying to run a force-directed web on Github.

It didn't work, and I got an `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'force' of undefined"` when I looked at the developer tools.

I'm kind of confused because my code works when I run it locally, just not over the Internet.

I then tried running the code on JSFiddle and it still didn't work. **Here is a link to a [Github repository](https://github.com/notesandedges/notesandedges.github.io) with all of the code, and here are the lines causing the issue (from the script.js file):**

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation()
.nodes(nodes)
.links([])
.gravity(.3)
.charge(-1000)
.size([w,h]
```

**If the code worked the nodes would show up on [this Github pages website](https://notesandedges.github.io/), but right now it's pretty blank.**

I've read some other threads on StackOverflow but the errors don't seem quite the same, and even when I tried the solutions nothing worked.

I think this issue may have something to do with d3.layout.force being renamed to d3.forceSimulation in version 4, but when I substituted that into my code it still didn't work.

Like I said, I'm new to d3 so I'm not sure how to update my code to accommodate the new version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You jsFiddle is horribly broken and you haven't provided enough code in the question to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my post and added links to the code on Github

Comment: Many things changed from v3 to v4. If you are using v4, just changing one function call often won't be enough to make code written for v3 work, especially for something like a force simulation. If you are using code that uses v3, use v3.

Comment: I tried that by adding the online link to v3 (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js), but it didn't work. I got 2 errors--one about the security of using an http address instead of https (except I don't know where to find an https link) and another saying d3 is not defined

Comment: WAIT nevermind I just added "s" to the http and it works now :/ Thanks so much!

Comment: Time to learn how to use d3 version 4...